# Scale invariance for images

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing, deep-belief-networks, scale-invariance

Given that images can be of vastly different resolutions, but neural networks are usually presented as having a fixed number of inputs, what are the standard techniques used to handle the difference between the number of NN inputs vs the number of pixels in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with different image sizes, the standard technique is down-sampling the images to a fixed resolution (see the famous [Krizhevsky ImageNet paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) for a example). To achieve scale invariance, the most used technique is convolutional networks. In [LeCun's website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/scale.html) there are some nice examples of LeNet-5 dealing with variances in scale.